# React native - Function call doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, frontend

Very new to react native and javascript...
I am trying to call a function and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is the fragment of code where the function is called:

```
<View style={styles.rows}>
   <renderButtons/>  //the function I want to call
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.interest_button} onPress={SettingsHandler}>
      <Text>{"  testdumdum  "}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>   //test to ensure nothing is wrong w function itself
</View>
```

and there is the function I want to call:

```
const renderButtons = () => {
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.interest_button} onPress={SettingsHandler}>
         <Text>{"  testsmartsmart  "}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   );
}
```

Only the container "testdumdum" appears, and I don't know why since the function does basically the same thing for now.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Hey, did you have time to try my suggestion? If it worked I would really appreciate it if you could accept my answer by pressing the check on the lefthand side of my answer. This also helps other people having the same issue who might stumble across your question.

Comment: Hi again! Yes it worked, sorry I didn't came back to this post to confirm. Still new to stack overflow and learning. 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your component with a capital letter:

> Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.

[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component)

so change *renderButtons* to *RenderButtons*